# dompdf creates defective PDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I want to create a pdf-file with dompdf pressing a button. Without the button all work fine, but as soon as I put the working php code in a if query to execute the dompdf-code the created pdf file is defective.
I am using dompdf 0.6.2 and this is my code.

```
<form method="post" >
    <p><input type="submit" name="mein_button" value="PDF erstellen" /></p> 
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mein_button']))
{   
    require_once("pdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
    function pdf_create($html, $filename, $paper, $orientation, $stream=TRUE) 
    {
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->set_paper($paper, $orientation);
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    } 
    $filename = 'file_name';
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $html = '<html><body>'.
            "<h1>PDF erstellen</h1>". 
            "<p>test test test</p>".
            '</body></html>';
    pdf_create($html, $filename, 'A4', 'portait');
}
?>
```

This code creates a a defective pdf-file. If I use only the code in the if query, the pdf file is ok.

I have not learned php, so I hope somebody can help me, because I can not find a solution.

Comment: Try move the generation of the PDF to the top. Also check that there are not error messages. Anything in the output buffer before generating the PDF can cause trouble.

Comment: oh man... serious... that was the problem. The pdf code to the top and it works... I tried everything, but that was to easy. Thanks